# Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
body: StreamBuilder(
  stream: db.collection('products').where('category', isEqualTo: 'category').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasError){
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Something error');
    }
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    final values = snapshot.data!.docs;
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: values!.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(values![index]['name']),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  },
),
```

> The following _CastError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>#c87c1):

Comment: could you include your firebase field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed `return` in your `if` blocks, so those widgets are not being returned, this redirect to the `snapshot.data!.docs`  widget which is `null` initially, change it to this:

```
 body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: db.collection('products').where('category', isEqualTo: 'category').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasError){
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Something error');
            return Text("error"); // add this to showcase the error
          }
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator(); // add this to show loading when data is fetching
          }
          final values = snapshot.data!.docs;
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: values!.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(values![index]['name']),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: stream: db.collection('products').where('category', isEqualTo: 'category' //catch data from db which is field category).snapshots(), //do you know with what code should i change cause i didn't get to display the category list

Comment: well since you got here, the error must be solved, yes I can tell you but you need to tell me what you're trying to get with that code and include a screenshot of how the DB looks like in your firebase console

Comment: i want to filter category product which my field name for the category in the DB is "category"

Comment: and what is it's value in your DB

Comment: for example, category: frozen foods

Comment: oh then you need to make it like this db.collection('products').where('category', isEqualTo: 'frozen foods').snapshots()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250644/discussion-between-peanut-and-gwhyyy).